# D3: Selecting a specific node from a different chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a mouseover in my charts. I have two charts on a single page, and they show the same data but in a different visualization. Now I'm trying to make it so that when you hover over a node from one chart, the corresponding node in the other chart also turns orange.

This is what I have under my mouseover for one of my charts:

```
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
              d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "orange");
              svg.selectAll("path").select(d)
                .style("fill", "orange");
          })
```

However, I can't seem to correctly address the corresponding node in the other chart. I imagine that `svg.selectAll("path").select(d)` is not the correct way to select a specific node in a different chart but I can't seem to figure out the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use data to select elements. I would give the element a unique ID based on the data and select according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select elements based on data in D3. I would assign a unique ID based on the data to each element and select according to that.